# SBT ManagedBean property credentialStore is ignored with SmartCloudOAuth2Endpoint

Tags: oauth-2.0, managed-bean, ibm-connections, ibm-sbt

Is seems that the credentialStore property is not being picked up when using the SBT. We have this property:

```
 <managed-property>
    <property-name>credentialStore</property-name>
    <value>CredStoreCloudant</value>
    </managed-property>
```

There is no change when I change the value to any odd name, while this name is clearly defined in the managed-beans.xml, like this :

```
<managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>CredStoreCloudant</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>com.eoffice.sbt.credentialstore.CloudantCredentialStore</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>application</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>
```

The managed-beans.xml is being used, when we change the property **clientID** , we do get the 401 error:

```
oauth_invalid_clientid
```

Which is expected behaviour.
The OAuth dance is performed nicely, but our code does not execute. It appears to be using the MemoryStore.

Comment: When I inspect the credentialstore in runtime it tells that this : com.ibm.sbt.security.credential.store.AnonymousSessionCredentialStore , is the implementation

Comment: it means there is no principal being found by the authentication layer

Comment: thanks @PaulBastide how can I force  my credentialstore to be used ?

Comment: maybe look at - https://github.com/OpenNTF/SocialSDK/blob/4f07c13180aa27152e08adf6440b6692e5a54d3b/samples/j2ee/templates/mysocial.webapp/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/managed-beans.xml  (it relies on a java.security.userprincipal being available in the request) so I'm not a 100% sure if your situation it's being generated / associated.

Comment: Maybe I need to clarify that we need to store the user's tokens in a cloudant database (after giving consent) and than later when an event comes in from "the cloud" with a identifier for that user (email address or phone number), we need to fetch the token from that database using this key. So there is , per definition. no security context for this user. Actually the SQL based datastore works this way and we have not had problems with this one ?

Comment: you'll have to extend the auth interceptor to work with this case.  by default it won't work.